# How to get two subplots side-by-side in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I just used following code to plot 2 subplot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax1.set_xlabel('Credit_History')
ax1.set_ylabel('Count of Applicants')
ax1.set_title("Applicants by Credit_History")
temp1.plot(kind='bar')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
temp2.plot(kind='bar')
ax2.set_xlabel('Credit_History')
ax2.set_ylabel('Probability of getting loan')
ax2.set_title("Probability of getting loan by credit history")
```

## I am getting following output

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

I am getting 3 plots i.e. 2 subplots as I intended, however the second one empty with titles as described. And third one underneath the two with bars for temp2 without the titles.

What I want are two subplots side by side with titles as described. Wondering what I have done wrong?

Comment: Check https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/ganged_plots.html. Although the given code is for vertically adjacent subplots, it is stated it can be applied for horizontally adjacent subplots as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce this exactly unless I put `plt.show()` between creating the second axes instance and `temp2.plot(kind='bar')`. If you aren't calling `plt.show()` (or clearing the buffer in some other way) you should try

```py
temp1.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax1)
temp2.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax2)
```

This should correctly use the two generated axes instances.

Comment: @Ali Don't forget to hit [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if this answer solved your problem, that way the question is marked as such for future users